# How to create menu at the top left corner of a window using openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am writing a game in openGL, in C++ at windows.

I need to add some menus and sub-menus at the top left corner of the window.

I've seen the popup menus on right click but I want the menus to be as any program like firefox, etc.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit #1:**

I've added a popup menu when a RMB is pressed with these:

```
glutCreateMenu(MenuSelect);
glutAddMenuEntry("Option1Name", option1);
glutAddMenuEntry("Option2Name", option2);
glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
```

and into the MenuSelect function I am printing some text.

Comment: @PeterWood: I've added what I've tried Peter.

Comment: Please consider using [Dear ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui), which is particularly suited to integration in game engines (for tooling), real-time 3D applications, fullscreen applications, embedded applications, or any applications on console platforms where operating system features are non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two choices:

- use some Windows API (or MFC), or QT, this will draw menus **on top** of OpenGL (using GDI, or other technology)
- use some third party library that will draw GUI **in** OpenGL (using its rendering commands)

For the latter option and for simple GUI I suggest http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools:anttweakbar

Comment: Given how simple it is to write a basic menu/window widget, it's worth considering just rolling a custom one for your requirements. If you need complex functions, there are plenty of GUI libraries (I prefer MyGUI, and CEGUI is fairly popular).

Comment: It's not simple at all. It would take days.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I solved it using Win32API.

1. Use the `CreateMenu` function to create the menu, then use the `SetMenu` function to set the menu to the window.
2. Because when menu is set, the drawing area of the program will be reduced, causing the coordinates to be offset when the mouse is clicked. We need to resize the window using the `AdjustWindowRect` and `MoveWindow` functions.
3. Because opengl will take over the callback function of the window, the menu command we set cannot be accepted by the program, we need to use the `SetWindowLongA` function to set the callback function of the window to the function we defined, and use the `CallWindowProc` function in the last line of the function we defined to call the opengl callback function.

Here is a example code:

```cpp
#define IDM_MENU_1      (1)         // menu id
static WNDPROC gl_wnd_proc;         // legacy opengl window proc function

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDM_MENU_1: // Do menu command here...
        }
    }
    }
    // Here we have to use `CallWindowProc` function
    return CallWindowProc(gl_wnd_proc,hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    // do `glutInit` first ...

    // 1. Create and set menu
    HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
    AppendMenuA(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_MENU_1, "Menu 1");
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA("GLUT", NULL); // "GLUT" is opengl window class name
    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);

    // 2. Adjust window size
    RECT rt = {0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT};
    AdjustWindowRect(&rt, GetWindowLongA(hWnd, GWL_STYLE), TRUE);
    MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, rt.right - rt.left, rt.bottom - rt.top, TRUE);

    // 3. Set window callback proc function
    gl_wnd_proc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongA(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG)MyWndProc);

    // do `glutMainLoop`
}
```

As for sub-menus, its creation method also continues to use `CreateMenu` and `AppendMenu`, you can refer to [Win32 API C++ Menu bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135494/win32-api-c-menu-bar)