# Win32 API C++ Menu bar

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to learn some basic win32 api.  I see to add items to the menu bar tutorials have mentioned to use something like:

```
hMenubar = CreateMenu();
hMenu = CreateMenu();

AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_NEW, L"&New");
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_OPEN, L"&Open");
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_QUIT, L"&Quit");
AppendMenuW(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenu, L"&File");
```

But in the default project for C++ Desktop in VS2013 has a File and Help menubar and inside they have Exit and About.  But all they do is have a switch like this in WndProc:

```
switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
```

I have a few questions.  How is it they add the file and help menu bars, as well as the about and exit items in the menubars without using the createmenu() and such?  WHat does IDM_ABOUT and IDM_EXIT mean?  They have those in the menus, but does just putting them in the switch statement add them to the menubars?  What is wmId and wmEvent and why is the switch on wmId?  What is actually adding those items to the menu bar?

If you need to see more code of my program it's just a non blank C++ Win32 Project in  VS2013

Thanks for any answers provided, and it would be appreicated if someone could point me in the direction of a good current as possible win32 api C++ tutorial.

Comment: `and it would be appreicated if someone could point me in the direction of a good current as possible win32 api C++ tutorial`  Any book by Charles Petzold.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to make menus. It can be done programmatically as you have shown, or it can be done with resource editor. In solution explorer, double-click the file with *.rc extension. You should see a window called "Resource view". Open the resource nodes until you see "Menu". You can add/modify/delete menu items. You can also make dialog boxes.

Each menu  item or dialog box button has an identification number, this number is passed through `WPARAM wParam`. In the above example `wmEvent` is not used, don't worry about it for now.

`IDM_ABOUT` is a number defined in resource file `#define IDM_ABOUT 101` (or it might be a different number). When menu item is clicked, then a message is sent with that number. You can catch the message and respond to it.

This is basic WinApi, it hasn't changed much in the last 10 or 20 years, any tutorial you find on Google is up to date.

Also, when you make a new menu item with resource editor, Visual Studio automatically creates an ID and assigns it to that menu item. You need to know what those ID's are. You can find out by hitting F4 key which brings up "Properties Window".

For example, if you type in a new menu item "&File New", the ID for that menu will be something like `ID_FILE_NEWFILE` which should be visible in "Properties Window".

This menu item will be just like `IDM_ABOUT`. It is sent to Windows Procedure function associated with that window.

For menu item messages:

- `message` is always set to `WM_COMMAND`
- `wParam` is the menu ID
- `lParam` is not used

Comment: For menus it's not important since HIWORD(wParam) is set to 0, but it is worth remembering that the control/menu id is encoded in LOWORD(wParam).

Answer (score 0):

Just to recap a bit.

You are using CreateMenu, AppendMenu, CreatePopupMenu to build a menu programmatically. Awesome.  Once you have your hMenubar, then, you can set it on your window using SetMenu and DrawMenu

```
::SetMenu(hWnd, hMenuBar);
::DrawMenu(hWnd);
```

At that point, Windows will send you messages about the menu.  Those, you handle in your Windows procedure exactly like shown in the example, but this time you use the IDs to you supplied when building your menu to understand what menu was picked.

I'll restate this from the example above, just for completeness.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case IDM_ABOUT:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
```

Now, you've build the menu bar yourself, but Windows can do that as well, using templates in the resource file and you can get that by calling ::LoadMenu.  From there, you can pass that menu as well to CreateWindow.  But, if you want to skip the step of loading the template yourself, what you can also do is specify the resource name of the menu on the window class.  This is from another example.

```
    wcx.lpszMenuName =  "MainMenu";    // name of menu resource 
wcx.lpszClassName = "MainWClass";  // name of window class 
wcx.hIconSm = LoadImage(hinstance, // small class icon 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(5),
    IMAGE_ICON, 
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), 
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), 
    LR_DEFAULTCOLOR); 

// Register the window class. 

return RegisterClassEx(&wcx);
```

In this way, you get a localized menu for your window from the resource file programmatically. For many applications, this is all you need.

Now we are in shape to answer your question.

You are using base APIs to create and manage your menus programmatically.  That's ok, and great in some circumstances, where you have to.  But, to make things a bit easier, Windows builds on top of that the ability to create menus from a data structure in the resource file.  By associating a menu resource name with the window class, Windows will go load the resource for you, then, walk through that structure, and call the InsertMenu, AppendMenu, CreateMenu, CreatePopupMenu just like you would.

So really, the answer is, you don't see it in your code, because these examples usually have the bit about creating the window class tucked in your WinMain or not far from it.